# How do I repair a broken chain on my old BMX bike?

Tags: maintenance

I have an old bmx and my chain broke yesterday. I bought a new chain from WalMart.  It is 300 links for 1 speed but I don't know what is the bmx speed (gear); it was rusted but I fixed it up.  I left my bmx at a program that opens tomorrow but I'm afraid its the wrong chain.

Comment: Are you asking how to repair the old chain or how to make the new chain work?

Comment: 300 links sounds weird. Most chains are around 114-116.

Comment: Basically you need a "chain breaker" tool and a detailed tutorial.  As to the right/wrong chain, basically the width of the chain is the only critical parameter.  There is one width for most single-speed bikes, then several different widths for multi-speed derailleur-style bikes, depending on how many speeds and what "generation" the bike is.

Comment: BMX chains use half size links, which is why you get 300.

Comment: @KimRyan yeah but is Walmart selling half link chains?

Comment: @jqninq , not sure, just know that half links seem to be standard on BMX.

Comment: @KimRyan I wouldn't say halflink chains are 'standard' on bmx. They might be used more there than in other disciplines, but they are not the standard.

Comment: Yes, walmart sells half link chains. A 1/8" half link chain should be fine. Just need a chain breaker to shorten it up to proper length.  http://www.walmart.com/ip/KMC-1-8-HL710-Half-Link-Chain/32301087.

Answer (score 2):

That chain should work OK. 300 links means probably a halflinks chain. Most BMX bikes are 1 speed and many use half link chains.

You will need a chain breaker though to get the length right. 
To get the length right, count the old links - DO NOT measure the actual length of the old one as the chain could be worn (stretched).